# How to scroll the list of notes in OneNote with mouse wheel on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, scrolling, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

Typically, when you move the cursor inside a list with a scrollbar, the mouse wheel would scroll that list. In OneNote, however, I can only scroll the note page itself, when the cursor is definitely within the list of notes (blue area in this illustration):

[image: fancy gif, it's a shame if you're not seeing it]

It doesn't seem to matter if the page can be scrolled or not, the mouse wheel doesn't scroll the list of notes when it's within the blue zone. I can only scroll it by interacting with the scrollbar with left mouse button.

It appears to be the issue with Windows 7 (maybe it's the OS, or maybe OneNote version for 7 has this bug). Windows 10 doesn't seem to have this problem at all.

Comment: Not all programs accept all forms of input.  Similarly, my mouse's "Back" and "Next" buttons don't trigger anything in programs where there's nothing appropriate to trigger.  I think I've worked in other Windows programs that ignore mouse scrolling, but don't recall them off the top of my head.  The developers have to intentionally program "Do this when a mousewheel up event is received" in order for something to happen.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage this appears to be an issue specific to Windows 7. In Windows 10 it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## New, much simpler solution using AutoHotKey

I've been looking for a way to avoid freezes caused by constant checks for the active window and also an overall simpler code solution. Here's what I made:

```
#ifWinActive ahk_class Framework::CFrame
    WheelUp::
        ControlGetFocus, control, A
        Loop 3
        SendMessage, 0x115, 0, 0, %control%, A
    Return

#ifWinActive ahk_class Framework::CFrame
    WheelDown::
        ControlGetFocus, control, A
        Loop 3
        SendMessage, 0x115, 1, 0, %control%, A
    Return
```

Change the `Loop 3` to `Loop 5` or however many lines you wish for one movement of the wheel to scroll.

---

## old solution using AutoIt

*Note: this solution may cause stuttering and occasional freezes on older CPUs or at full CPU load.*

I whipped up an AutoIt script which detects the cursor within the notes list area and if you scroll up or down, makes a click on the "up" and "down" buttons on the scrollbar. This works with multiple OneNote windows. You don't have to have focus on the window for the scroll to work, just hover over that list:

```
#include <AutoItConstants.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <MouseOnEvent.au3> ; get it from https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/64738-mouseonevent-udf/
#include <WinAPI.au3>
#include <Misc.au3>

_MouseSetOnEvent($MOUSE_WHEELSCROLLUP_EVENT, 'MouseWUp')
_MouseSetOnEvent($MOUSE_WHEELSCROLLDOWN_EVENT, 'MouseWDown')
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 2) ; 2 - substring mode

Global $clicks = 3 ; how many items to scroll per scroll, change this to 5, 8, 13, 42 or however fast you wanna scroll

Func MouseWUp($iEvent)
  If StringInStr(WinGetTitle($hWin), " - OneNote") Then

      ; check if cursor is within the notes list and not anywhere else
      Local $cur = MouseGetPos()
      Local $handle = $hWin ;WinGetHandle("[ACTIVE]")
      Local $wpos = WinGetPos($handle) ; returna array of x,y,w,h
      Local $cpos = ControlGetPos ($handle, "", "[CLASS:NetUIHWND; INSTANCE:5]")
      ;MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "title", "win2:" & $wpos[2] & "; win3:" & $wpos[3] & "; cp2:" & $cpos[2] & "; cp3:" & $cpos[3])

      If ($cur[0] > $wpos[0] + $wpos[2] - $cpos[2]) And ($cur[0] < $wpos[0] + $wpos[2]) Then

         Local $x = $cpos[2] - 2
         Local $y = 58
         ControlClick($handle, "", "[CLASS:NetUIHWND; INSTANCE:5]", "left", $clicks, $x, $y)

      EndIf

   EndIf
EndFunc

Func MouseWDown($iEvent)
   If StringInStr(WinGetTitle($hWin), " - OneNote") Then

      Local $cur = MouseGetPos()
      Local $handle = $hWin ;WinGetHandle("[ACTIVE]")
      Local $wpos = WinGetPos($handle)
      Local $cpos = ControlGetPos ($handle, "", "[CLASS:NetUIHWND; INSTANCE:5]")

      If ($cur[0] > $wpos[0] + $wpos[2] - $cpos[2]) And ($cur[0] < $wpos[0] + $wpos[2]) Then

         Local $x = $cpos[2] - 2
         Local $y = $cpos[3] - 8
         ControlClick($handle, "", "[CLASS:NetUIHWND; INSTANCE:5]", "left", $clicks, $x, $y)

      EndIf
   EndIf
EndFunc

; https://stackoverflow.com/a/11270659
Func _WindowFromPoint($iX,$iY)
    Local $stInt64,$aRet,$stPoint=DllStructCreate("long;long")
    DllStructSetData($stPoint,1,$iX)
    DllStructSetData($stPoint,2,$iY)
    $stInt64=DllStructCreate("int64",DllStructGetPtr($stPoint))
    $aRet=DllCall("user32.dll","hwnd","WindowFromPoint","int64",DllStructGetData($stInt64,1))
    If @error Then Return SetError(2,@error,0)
    If $aRet[0]=0 Then Return SetError(3,0,0)
    Return $aRet[0]
EndFunc

Local $hControl, $hWin, $hOldWin, $aMousePos
$hOldWin = ""
While True ;Not _IsPressed("1B")
    $aMousePos = MouseGetPos()
    $hControl=_WindowFromPoint($aMousePos[0],$aMousePos[1])
    ; Since _WindowFromPoint() can return 'sub' windows, or control handles, we should seek the owner window
    $hWin=_WinAPI_GetAncestor($hControl,2)
    If $hWin <> $hOldWin Then
        ;TrayTip("Window Info","Window under mouse = " & WinGetTitle($hWin), 1)
        $hOldWin = $hWin
    EndIf
    Sleep(10)
WEnd
```

I haven't figured out how to prevent the scrolls from affecting the note page itself. If someone finds a way to block the scroll event from reaching the main note area from within the notes list area, please share your solution so we could combine the scripts for best results.