# How to see which mouse events a touchpad sends when scrolling?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, touchpad, scrolling

This question comes from trying to find a way to [make the mouse wheel scroll OneNote's list of notes in Windows 7.](https://superuser.com/questions/1138876/how-to-scroll-the-list-of-notes-in-onenote-with-mouse-wheel-on-windows-7)

Apparently my netbook's touchpad driver sends such scroll events (when doing a two-finger vertical swipe) that makes OneNote scroll the list of notes on the right as intended. Normally scrolling with a usb mouse's wheel doesn't produce the wanted effect.

I suspect I could remap the mouse scroll event for all OneNote windows to that special mouse scroll event which the touchpad driver sends using AutoIt/AutoHotKey and the like. But for that I want to find out what window message the touchpad sends.

How can I see what scroll events are sent so I could solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

[Winspector Spy app shows a log of all window messages sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213403/windows-event-message-viewer-for-viewing-messages-sent-by-postmessage-function) and it allows to filter by specific windows. So I've managed to get a log of all of them, and now I'm gonna have to figure out which one of all of them is the scroll message that I want.